# How to use path variable in @Preauthorize

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-security, pre-authentication

I have a situation where i need to pass the path variable as a argument to the preauthorize

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/page/{cmd}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole(#cmd)") 
     public void method(@PathVariable String cmd, HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response){
// my stuff
}
```

It is not working.can anyone suggest me how to use the path variable in pre authorize please.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring Security's `@PreAuthorize` is used for authorizing access to methods. It doesn't know really much about Spring MVC, in particular about its `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Names like `#cmd` will refer to method parameters, and your `cmd` parameter is null. Change it to:

```
@PathVariable("cmd") String cmd
```

This way, `cmd` path variable will be bound to `cmd` method parameter, which will then be bound by `#cmd` in `@PreAuthorize`.